# Why does Azure Functions JSON serialisation convert class property names to camel case and lower case?

Tags: c#, json, azure-functions, json.net

I have an Azure Function V4. It is a Http triggered function returning IActionResult.
My expectation of the output JSON should be property names matching exact letter casing of property names of the C# class. but the JSON serialization converts property names to camel case and lower case.

I want the JSON object property names letter casing to exactly match that of the C# class member names of that model.

C# Object

```
public string JobId { get; set; }
public List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
public Tags Tags { get; set; }
    

public class Contact
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
}
    
public class Tags
{
    public string GROUPCONTACT { get; set; }
}
```

JSON result Actual

```
{
    "jobId": null,
    "contacts": [
        {
            "firstName": "dummy"
        }
    ],
    "tags": {
        "groupcontact": "dummy"
    }
}
```

Expected JSON result

```
{
    "JobId": null,
    "Contacts": [
        {
            "firstName": "dummy"
        }
    ],
    "Tags": {
        "GROUPCONTACT": "dummy"
    }
}
```

Comment: Does [Specifying JsonSerializerOptions in .NET 6 isolated Azure Function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74427929/3744182) answer your question?  You would need `options.PropertyNamingPolicy = null` rather than `JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase`.  If not, could you show how you are returning your `IActionResult`?

Comment: I hope you don't mind but I have edited your post's title to include a question I think is relevant for the body.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

As @*dbc* mentioned in the comments, you have to specify
`PropertyNamingPolicy = null` instead of `PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase` to keep the property names as unchanged.

```cs
var serializeOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions 
{
 PropertyNamingPolicy = null 
};
```

If you are using [camel case property naming policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/customize-properties?pivots=dotnet-7-0#use-camel-case-for-all-json-property-names)  (`PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase`), you can use`[JsonPropertyName]` attributes to override the property names as shown below:

```cs
    public class Contact
    {
        public string firstName { get; set; }
    }
        
    public class Tags
    {
        [JsonPropertyName(Details)]
        public string GROUPCONTACT { get; set; }
    }
```

Output:

```cs
    {
        "contacts": [
            {
                "firstName": "XXXXX"
            }
        ],
        "tags": {
            "Details": "XXXXX"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Heads up, [JsonPropertyName] *should* override this, but does not.