# enabling Newtonsoft json with .Net 7 isolated Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure-functions, json.net, azure-functions-isolated

I have a C# .Net 7 ISOLATED Azure function app where I'm trying to return json results from classes that are decorated with Newtonsoft attributes:

```
public class AuthResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("extended_status_code")]
    public int? Status { get; set; }
}
```

But for some reason the property attribute is ignored.

I've tried to add the following package to all my projects to (hopefully) bring Newtonsoft in:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson 7.0.10
```

And in my Program.cs HostBuilder I tried both:

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {
      services.AddMvcCore().AddNewtonsoftJson()
      --or--
      services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson()
      ...
```

to no avail.

So it appears it's using the default System.Text.Json because if I change the json attribute to

```
public class AuthResponse
{
    [JsonPropertyName("extended_status_code")]
    public int? Status { get; set; }
}
```

I do see the expected json field name override.

Here's the function:

```
  [Function("Login")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> LoginAsync(
      [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "auth/login")] HttpRequestData request,
      CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {

    return new JsonResult(new AuthResponse());
  }
```

Am I missing something in building the HostBuilder?  Maybe bringing in the 'wrong' Newtonsoft?

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74427826/specifying-jsonserializeroptions-in-net-6-isolated-azure-function

// define your global custom JSON serializer options
        s.Configure<JsonSerializerOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.AllowTrailingCommas = true;
            options.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
            options.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
            options.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
        });

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue as you and you are correct in that it is using the default System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer to serialize responses.

In my case, this was due to calling the ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication extension method on HostBuilder. By default, this will register IActionResultExecutor<JsonResult> with implementation type SystemTextJsonResultExecutor (see AddMvcCoreServices method in [MvcCoreServiceCollectionExtensions](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/DependencyInjection/MvcCoreServiceCollectionExtensions.cs) class).

The Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson Nuget package contains it's own implementation type of IActionResultExecutor<JsonResult> ([NewtonsoftJsonResultExecutor](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.NewtonsoftJson/src/NewtonsoftJsonResultExecutor.cs)). To use this implementation, an extension method - [AddNewtonsoftJson](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.NewtonsoftJson/src/DependencyInjection/NewtonsoftJsonMvcCoreBuilderExtensions.cs) - on IMvcCoreBuilder is provided. However, the Azure Functions HostBuilder does not provide (or I cannot find) a reference to this type to call this extension method. Looking at the implementation of this method, I could see it just calls an internal method (AddServicesCore), which accepts a service collection. Calling this internal method was what allowed me to get over the hurdle of not having an IMvcCoreBuilder instance.

Below is the approach I took. Unfortunately, it uses reflection. If someone else is able to come up with a better approach, that would be appreciated.

1. Add the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson/) Nuget package to your project
2. Create an extension method on IFunctionsWorkerApplicationBuilder to allow your Function App. to 'use' the Newtonsoft.Json serializer

```
    public static IFunctionsWorkerApplicationBuilder UseNewtonsoftJson(this IFunctionsWorkerApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        var newtonsoftMvcCoreBuilder = typeof(NewtonsoftJsonMvcCoreBuilderExtensions);
        var addServicesCore = newtonsoftMvcCoreBuilder.GetMethod("AddServicesCore", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        addServicesCore.Invoke(null, new[] { builder.Services });
        return builder;
    }
```

3. Call the previously created extension method when configuring your Function App.

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication(config =>
    {
        config.UseNewtonsoftJson();
    })
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        // Configure services...
    }).Build();

await host.RunAsync();
```

Comment: you seem to be the only person on the internet I can find who solved this problem, but I can't get your solution to work because I don't have any method called ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication. What is this?

Comment: Sorry, this extension method is available as part of the Nuget package Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore, which will need to be added to your project. Also remember to include the using directive in your Program.cs class (i.e. using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;)

Comment: Here is an example not using reflection: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/blob/16a995deb65b44873cd3a56b5e6d4d3c22d64b7d/samples/Configuration/Program.cs#L58C124-L58C124

Comment: @mlienau, yes I believe that will work for HTTP-triggered functions using the [Built-in model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#built-in-http-model). However, that example doesn't work for functions that utilise the [ASP.NET Core integration model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#aspnet-core-integration). See my original answer regarding calls to ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication() and the registration of IActionResultExecutor<JsonResult> implementations in the DI container.

Answer (score 1):

In .NET 8 this should work:

```
.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
{
    services.AddMvcCore().AddNewtonsoftJson();
}
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that you'll need the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson package to make this work. But this was exactly the solution I needed

Answer (score -1):

Need to add below using statement in class file where `JsonProperty` attribute is required

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

Please refer to my sample github repo using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson`

https://github.com/riyazkittur/AddNewtonsoftJson

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I already have that 'using' in every class implementation file that has the attribute.  Otherwise it would not compile.  And my problem is with Azure, not in-process WebAPI.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
....
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

Comment: To change over to WebApplicationBuilder versus HostBuilder?  I don't think you are supposed to use WebApplicationBuilder for Isolated Azure Fucntions.